git menu options not available in intellij
I have installed IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.4 (Community Edition). But I see that git related menu options like 'git history', 'git blame' etc are no more available. I remember earlier versions had them.
Am I missing any configuration?

Does your project have git enabled?
